# How are MS office apps are able to be installed on both office online products(like excel online) and MS office offline products like(Excel 2013)

Tags: ms-office, office-addins, office-app

I have created an outlook add-in using VSTO. And I recently found that you can't upload VSTO add-ins to office store. As it is only for apps developed using web technologies.
Since these apps use web technologies so it seemed fine that they work well with MS office online products.But I couldn't understand that how they are able to work with the offline products.

Answer (score 0):

Napa apps can run in both Office 365 and local instances of office products.

They have been around since 2012, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jasonz/archive/2012/07/17/introducing-napa-office-365-development-tools.aspx

Ron.

Comment: So, to run these napa apps do we always need internet connection.

Comment: Yes, you always need an Internet connection to run Office Web Add-ins